# Shell script doesn't run

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, scripting

Can someone help and tell me why this isn't working?

I have checked the script and solved some problems but it still doesn't works fine and I can't find the mistake.

```
#!/bin/bash

#variabelen

IP="192.168.0."
array=($@)

#functies
```

What's wrong with the array? My linux told me that there is a syntax error on line 12 so with that array but he doesn't tell me what.

```
function Sorteer(){

array=($(printf '%s\n' "$@"|sort -nu))
for i in ${array[@]};do
ping -c -1 "IP"$i
done

}

function Telbij(){
# given number $i +200
    b=$(( $i + 200 ))    
    if (( b > 255 ))
    then
        echo "Neem kleiner getal";  
    else
    ping -c 1 "IP"$b;
    fi
}

function XXYY() {
#ping 65-68 = ping 65 66 67 68
start=${1%-*}
end=${1#*-}
for ((i=start;i<=end;i++));do
    ping -c 1 "$IP"$i
done
}
```

The mistake is in the if else function: http://prntscr.com/7gr8yf

But I don't know what that means: "The mentioned parser error was in this else clause."

```
if [ "$#" -eq 0 ]; then   
        echo "Er moet minimaal 1 parameter worden meegegeven "
        exit 0                 
   else

case

-h -help ) echo "Geef de laatste cijfers van het IP-adres van de pc's om te testen.";;

XX-YY ) XXYY;;

-t ) Telbij;;

- sort ) Sorteer;;

esac

fi
done
```

Comment: Sorry, no, we cannot help if you don't say what the actual problem is. "it still doesn't works fine" is pretty vague, don't you think? Tell us what is wrong with the behavior. _Be specific!_

Comment: Replace temporarily the first line with `#!/bin/bash -vx`  during the debugging phase. You'll get some trace.

Comment: Another useful tool for debugging shell: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: ow thanks, i will use shellcheck.net first.

Comment: If you run a Bash script with `sh scriptname` you would get a syntax error for the array initialization.  You cannot use Bash constructs when running the script with `sh`, even when `sh` is a symlink to `bash` (in which case Bash will run in POSIX compatibility mode).  This is a *massive* FAQ; see item #2 in the [bash tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info).

Answer (score 1):

Don't know what's specifically not working but,

in `Sorteer` function you should double quote array expansions to avoid re-splitting elements.
Try change to following:

```
function Sorteer(){

array=($(printf '%s\n' "$@"|sort -nu))
for i in "${array[@]}";do
ping -c -1 "IP"$i
done
```

}

Now your `case` operator should be like:

```
case $some_value in

-help ) echo "Geef de laatste cijfers van het IP-adres van de pc's om te testen.";;

XX-YY ) XXYY;;

-t ) Telbij;;

-sort ) Sorteer;;

esac
```

This will fix your `if` issue as well

Comment: It gives me the error with '(' but what's wrong. Also my case is not good, line 42.

Comment: tnx. I thougt you always had to use if else if you use case.

Comment: My pleasure :)  If your found my answer correct, please vote for it. Thx